# Run SQL Server Agent and Database Engine as Network Service or System

Tags: sql-server-2008

It's been a long time since I've had to install SQL Server.  I'm doing it for a source control system called Plastic SCM on my system.

I'm about to finish the wizard asking me a plethora of questions, and I'm at the `Service Accounts` tab under `Server Configuration`, it's asking me if I want to use `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` or `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` to run either `SQL Server Agent` or `SQL Server Database Engine`.

My question is, what is the different between these accounts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the screenshots here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2008/07/15/installing-sql-server-2008-rc0.aspx

Comment: Thanks, good article.  I should have phrased my original question better.  What I really wanted was an explanation of the differences between the accounts

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use a separate Active Directory account.